# perl(Inline) module is needed

Tags: centos, package-management, perl

I decided to view the contents of buffers cache using the tool called `fincore` while trying to install I have been getting the error as

```
warning: fincore-1.9-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 6b8d79e6: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(Inline) is needed by fincore-1.9-1.el6.rf.x86_64
```

I have installed Perl already in my machine and I googled on getting the dependency file but I don't find so. What is the problem here?

I am using CentOS 6.5

Comment: try `yum install perl-Inline` first

Answer (score 0):

EPEL 6 has a packaged version of the perl-Inline module. To install and enable EPEL:

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

yum should then be able to install the dependency when installing the fincore RPM. You can also explicitly install the dependency via:

```
yum install -y perl-Inline
```